# Unit test for getting current UTC date-time

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a method like this:

```
public Date getCurrentUtcDateTime() {
        // Return UTC time
}
```

I want to create a unit test with JUnit for it.

```
assertEquals( ??????
```

What's the right approach?

1. If I write unit test code to calculate the UTC current time, it's not good because I would essentially be rewriting the entire function. In addition to this the milliseconds of the two datetimes will not be the same.
2. If I just check that the result is not null, it's not good - the result might still be wrong.

What else should I try? What's the right way to write a unit test for this function?

Comment: What do you want to test? If it match a pattern? Use Pattern.

Comment: Given that the function you'd be testing should just be `return new Date()`, so it really worth testing it?

Comment: it's not new Date() only, it's returning UTC.

Answer (score 1):

> If I write unit test code to calculate the UTC current time, it's not good because I would essentially be rewriting the entire function

Sometimes that's the only way you can test something. Perhaps there is another approach you can use to get the same time? I.e. use Joda-time not standard Java classes, or vice versa.

One approach for testing could be (psuedo-code):

```
startTime = getUTCTimeUsingAlternativeMethod();
resultTime = classUnderTest.getCurrentUtcDateTime();
endTime = getUTCTimeUsingAlternativeMethod();

validateThat(startTime <= resultTime);
validateThat(resultTime <= endTime);
```

But as [Jon points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402232/unit-test-for-getting-current-utc-date-time/25402392#comment39621072_25402232), a method this simple may not require testing. Your time may be better spent testing other methods in more detail.

Comment: That said, I love this approach. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

So I have come across this multiple times. And in a lot of cases getting the before and after time (as suggested) works well. However, I have had problems with this in cases where the time is converted to a String or some such where I need the exact time to be able to create a good test. For this reason I created a mechanism to *control time* (just not the space-time continuum).

I have a class called [DateSupplier](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/libex/src/main/java/org/libex/concurrent/DateSupplier.java) which has methods like `getCurrentTime()` and `getCurrentDateTime`. The default behavior returns `new Date()`.

I then have a JUnit Rule [DateController](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/testlibex/src/main/java/org/libex/test/concurrent/DateController.java) that can be used to control explicitly what `DateSupplier` returns. The `DateController` Rule is in a test library so should not be deployed with production code. After each test it sets the behavior of `DateSupplier` back to the default behavior of returning the correct current `Date`.

```
public Date getCurrentUtcDateTime() {
    // Return UTC time
     Date date = DateSupplier.getCurrentDate();
}

public class MyTest{

     @Rule
     public DateController dateController = new DateController();

     private Date currentTime;

     @Before
     public void setup(){
        dateController.setCurrentTimeToNow();
        currentTime = DateSupplier.getCurrentTime();
     }

     @Test
     public void myTest(){
        Date value = getCurrentUtcDateTime();

        // verify
        Date utcDate = // convert currentTime to UTC
        assertThat(value, equalTo(utcDate));
     }
}
```